# What's so special about the discriminant in the form $b^2 - 4ac$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, discriminant

The following is the quadratic formula derived by completing the square:

$$x = -\frac{b}{2a}  \pm \sqrt{ \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{c}{a}} \tag{1}$$

This equation is equivalent:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a} \tag{2}$$

We can obtain $(2)$ from $(1)$ by trying to simplify the term under the $\sqrt{\dots}$ as much as possible.

I've always felt there is no such thing as **"the quadratic formula"**, and that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equally arbitrary.

---

Everything the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ can do, so can $\frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{c}{a}$ (literally because  it's just a scalar multiple of the other).

What makes the form $b^2 - 4ac$ so special? It does not seem to be "arbitrary"? As stated in the Wikipedia article for it:

> The discriminant is widely used in polynomial factoring, number theory, and algebraic geometry

I could try to "formalize" the notion of:

- *"Maximally simplifying the term under the $\sqrt{\dots}$"*
- *"The discriminant in $(1)$ normalized is the discriminant in $(2)$"*

However this does not seem intuitive nor correct.

---

Why is the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ not arbitrary/special?

Does it appear elsewhere more "naturally"?

Comment: If $a=0$ the regular definition still works :)

Comment: I can also write it as $x=\frac{-b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{4a^{2}b^{2}-16a^{3}c}}{4a^{2}}$, so we have $4a^{2}b^{2}-16a^{3}c$, which works for $a = 0$.

Comment: Does it? I thought $0/0$ is a bit of a pickle

Comment: Ah sorry I see what you mean, but no, it won't work the same. It'll give you $0$ instead of $b$ for $a=0$

Comment: It is a bit funny applying the definition to first degree polynomials either way, admittedly.

Comment: I upvoted all answers.
I want to point out it also follows from matrix theory and others.
And there is also the lesser known formula with the square root in the denom ofcourse.

Comment: In the case of quadratics, the sign of the discriminant tells you how many real solutions there are. If positive, you get 2 real roots, if 0, 1 rea read, and if negative, there are only complex roots. In this sense, it is arbitrary up to a multiplicative factor, however this definition is more consistent with higher order discriminants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The discriminant generalizes to polynomials of any degree (not just quadratics). Given a polynomial $$p(x) =a_{n}\prod^{i}_{1\dots n} (x-r_{i}) $$
the discriminant is the formula for:

$$\Delta = a_{n}^{2n-2}\prod_{i<j}(r_{j}-r_{i})^2$$

---

For a second degree polynomial:
$$p_2(x)  = ax^2 + bx + c = \\  = a(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})$$

the second degree discriminant formula gives:
$$\Delta_{2} = b^2 - 4ac =\\ =  a^2 \;(r_{2}-r_{1})^2 $$

---

For a third degree polynomial:
$$p_3(x) =  ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = \\ a(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})(x-r_{3}) $$

the third degree discriminant formula is:
$$\Delta_{3} = 18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2 = \\ = a^4 \;(r_{2}-r_{1})^2(r_{3}-r_{1})^2(r_{3}-r_{2})^2 $$

---

The discriminant gives the (squared) product of the differences of distinct roots of a $n$'th degree polynomial, times the top coefficient to the power $2n-2$.

There exists formulas for higher degrees. The general formula for the discriminant is the determinant of the [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$, divided by the top coefficient of $p$.

---

The discriminant formula can be characterized by the following properties:

1. It's an algebraic  formula in the coefficients of our polynomial. That is, it uses only sums and products of the coefficients, no fractions.
2. It is equal to $0$ if and only if the polynomial has repeated roots. That is, it **discriminates** the polynomials which don't have $n$ distinct complex roots. This can be seen by looking at its expression in terms of the polynomial roots.
3. It is the simplest formula with the above properties. Specifically, it is a divisor for any formula satisfying them. This makes it unique up to a constant factor.

More info on the generalized discriminant formula can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: A small typo: you want $\Delta = a_{n}^{2n-2}\prod_{i<j}(r_{j}-r_{i})^2$ (rather than $r_1$)

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the quadratic discriminant as $\,b^2 - 4ac\,$ makes it consistent with the definition of the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) for higher degree polynomials.

In general, for a polynomial $\,p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x +a_0\,$ of degree $n$ with roots $\,x_1, x_2, \ldots.x_n\,$ the discriminant can be defined as $\,\Delta = a_n^{2n-2} \prod_{1 \le i \lt j \le n}(x_i-x_j)^2\,$. For the quadratic $\,ax^2+bx+c\,$ this reduces to $\,\Delta = a^2(x_1-x_2)^2 = b^2 - 4ac\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically for a parabola with equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ the coordinates of the vertex are given by $V=(x_v,y_v)=\left(-\frac b{2a},-\frac {\Delta}{4a}\right)$ such that the condition on the sign of $\Delta$ with the sign of $a$ determine the number of solutions for the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Moreover $\Delta$ appears in all the key parameter for the parabola as the focus $F=(x_f,y_f)=\left(-\frac b{2a},-\frac {1-\Delta}{4a}\right)$ and the related diretrix with equation $y=-\frac {\Delta}{4a}-\frac {1}{4a}$.

---

In multivariable calculus, in the simpler case of $2$ variables, the study of the nature of stationary points can be done with reference to the quadratic form

$$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2= \begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&\frac b2\\\frac b2&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

and of the Hessian determinant $$H=\begin{bmatrix}a&\frac b2\\\frac b2&c\end{bmatrix}=ac-\frac{b^2}4=-\frac{\Delta}4$$